# NSResponder and multiple NSTableView - who sent message?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsresponder

I've got two NSTableView in a single NSViewController, and each has their own NSArrayController to handle what exists.  I'm now trying to wire up the Edit->Delete button.  How do I know, when the delete method is called, 'who' sent that message?

Specifically I want to know whether I was clicked into the first table view or the second one when I then chose the Delete menu item.  The 'sender' to the delete method is just the NSMenuItem so I can't back-track that to the table.

Comment: Usually you'd hook up the delete button to the NSArrayController.

Comment: Can you give a little more specifics on how that's done please?   Since I have two array controllers, I'm not sure how to link things.  This is my first Cocoa app...I normally do iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `firstResponder` of the window and follow `nextResponder` until you find a table view.

Comment: Thanks!  The firstResponder is the NSTableView, which is perfect.